# How to correctly check for two conditions?

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I am working on a homework problem.
I want that calling this function: **numberConverter([1,2,3,'4','5', {}, 33])**

returns this string: **"2 were converted to numbers: 4,5; 1 couldn't be converted"**

That means that the function:
- loops through the array
- counts all strings that can be converted into numbers
- pushes those instances in an array
- counts all values that couldn't be converted into numbers
- returns "no need for conversion" if all values are numbers

When I run my code it returns:
**"1 were converted to numbers: NaN; 0 couldn't be converted"**

I went through the code with the debugger and it does not get hold of "4" and "5" as strings that can be turned into numbers.

Why?

My attempt:

```
function numberConverter(arr) {
    var countConverted = 0;
    var converted = [];
    var countNotConverted = 0;
    var countNumbers = 0;

    for (var x of arr) {
        if (isNaN(x) == true && typeof parseInt(x)=="number") {
            converted.push(parseInt(x));
            countConverted++
        } else if (isNaN(x) == true && typeof parseInt(x)!="number") {
            countNotConverted++
        } else if (isNaN(x) == false) {
            countNumbers++
        }
    }

    if (arr.length+1 == countNumbers) {
        return `no need for conversion`
    } else {
        return `${countConverted} were converted to numbers: ${converted}; ${countNotConverted} couldn't be converted`
    }
}
```

Correct code:

```
function numberConverter(arr) {

    var converted = []
    var counterConverted = 0
    var counterNotConverted = 0

    for (var c of arr) {

    if(typeof(c) != "number") { 
        if (isNaN(c)) {
            counterNotConverted++;
        } else {
            // c = parseInt(c); done in line 16
            counterConverted++;
            converted.push(parseInt(c))
        }
    }
    }
    if (counterConverted == 0) {
        return "no need for conversion"
    } else {
        //return counterConverted+" were converted to numbers: "+ converted + "; "+counterNotConverted+" couldn't be converted"
        return `${counterConverted} were converted to numbers: ${converted}; ${counterNotConverted} coudln't be converted`
    }
}
```

**EDIT- CHANGES WORK ALMOST**

```
function numberConverter(arr) {
    var countConverted = 0;
    var converted = [];
    var countNotConverted = 0;
    var countNumbers = 0;

    for (var x of arr) {
        if (typeof(x) != "number" && typeof parseInt(x)=="number") {
            converted.push(parseInt(x));
            countConverted++
        } else if (typeof(x) != "number" && typeof parseInt(x)!="number") {
            countNotConverted++
        } else if (isNaN(x) == false) {
            countNumbers++
        }
    }

    if (arr.length+1 == countNumbers) {
        return `no need for conversion`
    } else {
        return `${countConverted} were converted to numbers: ${converted}; ${countNotConverted} couldn't be converted`
    }
}
```

Oddly, it converts, pushes and returns {} as NaN like this

"3 were converted to numbers: 4,5,NaN; 0 couldn't be converted"

instead of counting it as not being able to convert. Why? Almost there!

**COMMENT:** Just found out that typeof parseInt({}) is "number".

Comment: `parseInt()` either returns a number/integer or `NaN`. But `typeof NaN` will also be `"number"`.

Comment: `isNaN('5')` will be `true` or `false`?

Comment: condition didn't meet in the first function, if you place else condition then it will work as expected.

Comment: @Andreas why is isNaN("5") false? "5" is not a number because it's a string so it should result true!

Comment: What is this "Correct code"? It that what your teacher wrote?

Comment: [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN): _"The `isNaN()` function determines whether a value is `NaN` or not. **Note: coercion inside the `isNaN` function has interesting rules;** you may alternatively want to use `Number.isNaN()`, as defined in ECMAScript 2015."_

Comment: @Georg this is one working example when testing against several arrays. I'm sure there are "better", shorter, cleaner options. Don't forget this is beginners level

Comment: thx @Andreas ... at times javascript seems like a law codex in the sense that you really have to check the meaning of a statement and not just assume what might be logical in spoken language "is not a number" then quickly differs from "isNaN"

Comment: _"you really have to check the meaning of a statement and not just assume what might be logical"_ - That's true for every language ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the track. Just check three condition: 
First condition: is it number?

```
if (typeof(x) === 'number') {
    countNumbers++;
}
```

Second Condition: is possible to convert to number?

```
 else if(!isNaN(x)) {
     countConverted++;
     converted.push(parseInt(x));
 }
```

and Last condition: what else can't be converted

```
else {
    countNotConverted++;
}
```

Rest of the code is nice to go...
Working Example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafee/pbgx879d/25/)

Comment: Thx .... your second condition was eye opening !

I know figured this for loop: 

for (var x of arr) {
  if (typeof(x) != "number" && !isNaN(x)) {
   converted.push(parseInt(x));
   countConverted++
  } else if (typeof(x) != "number" && isNaN(x)) {
   countNotConverted++
  } else if (isNaN(x) == false) {
   countNumbers++
  }
 }